# DTC not working when two transactions are being executed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server, msdtc

I'm working on SQL Server 2008 and I'm trying to execute a stored procedure which updates a table and executes another stored procedure on a linked server.

The point is it works when no update is made, just like this:

[test_DTC] on [Server1]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_DTC] 
@UserId int,
@Status tinyint
AS
BEGIN

    EXEC [Server2].[Database].[dbo].[test_DTC];

END

GO
```

[test_DTC] on [Server2]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_DTC] 

AS
BEGIN

    PRINT 'Done'

END

GO
```

Execute on Server1:

```
EXEC [test_DTC]
```

Result:

```
Done
```

But when I include the UPDATE on Server1 procedure, it fails.

[test_DTC] on [Server1]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_DTC] 
@UserId int,
@Status tinyint
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE 
       Users
    SET 
       Status=@Status
    WHERE 
       UserId=@UserId;

    EXEC [Server2].[Database].[dbo].[test_DTC];

END

GO
```

[test_DTC] on [Server2]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_DTC] 

AS
BEGIN

    PRINT 'Done'

END

GO
```

Execute on Server1:

```
EXEC [test_DTC]
```

Result

```
Provider OLE DB "SQLNCLI10" from linked server "[Server2]" returned message "The transaction has already been implicitly or explicitly committed". Msg 7391, Level16, State 2, Procedure [Server2].[Database].[dbo].[test_DTC], Line 19

The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "Server2" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this is the [MSDN Blog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c74f95a8-7b3b-42d2-b9d7-3c49b9b8d2a1/exception-the-transaction-has-already-been-implicitly-or-explicitly-committed-or-aborted?forum=windowstransactionsprogramming)

it says

> The reason is that when transactions propagate from one machine to another they include their machine name/DNS name along with it.  When it arrives on the other machine, it will use this name to attempt to communicate back to the originator machine.  If this communication fails then distributed transactions will not work in the system.

Microsoft has provided a [Detailed Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/954950/fix-error-message-when-you-run-a-distributed-query-in-sql-server-2005) on the same

Comment: Hi both!, I'm affraid that's not the cause of the problem because first attemp works fine and gives back the answer "Done" from the second server to the first, so communications are working fine :(

Comment: @JorgeAmarRamón I have added one more article from Microsoft check that too

Comment: I've seen that article sais it'll be fixed with and cumulative update package 958186, but it's already included in SQL Server 2008 SP1, and this server has SP3